# How to Read the serial port name from text box (editable)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyserial

I am trying to open the serial port in Linux with Python 2.7 PyQt4 with the below code and it works fine:

```
serialport.port = "/dev/ttyACM1"
serialport.baudrate = 115200       
serialport.open()
```

I don't want to hard-code the serial port name as above. I want to take the serial port name as the input from user from an editable text box:

```
textbox.setText("/dev/ttyACM1")
serialport.port = textbox.text()
serialport.baudrate = 115200       
serialport.open()
```

But I am unable to convert `textbox.text()` format to `serialport.port`.
The following error occurs:

> ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not < class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString' >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PyQt and have something like this:

```
w = QWidget()
textbox =  QLineEdit(w)
```

right?!

The error message tells you that the result of `textbox.text()`is of type `QString`. But you need a `string` instead.
You can simply convert the result using `str(textbox.text())`

```
serialport.port = str(textbox.text())
```

should solve the problem.